# Stuff overflowing the "are you a robot" screen

Tags: bug, captcha

When clicking the "post question" button, I was prompted with the "are you a robot" screen. Right away I noticed something.

[image: stuff overflowing]

The text and the reCAPTCHA are overflowing the "are you a robot" dialog! Could someone fix this?

Comment: Congratulations, you passed the test!

Comment: I passed the test? What?

Comment: Sorry, bad joke.  I meant that you passed the "are you a robot?" test by identifying that it was broken.

Comment: Ahhhhh, that explains it

Comment: Could you mention the browser version?

Comment: The joke’s on you @RyanM: the OP’s question and comment were automated posts made by their AI bot.

Comment: @AndrewT. My broswers version is microsoft edge 103